# How to implement postgraphile in Express.js

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

I have not found much documentation about integrating postgraphile in express.js, please if someone knows in a detailed way about integrating these technologies, I would be very grateful. Thank you so much
The documentation only gives me this:

If someone gives me an example of a guide I would appreciate it.

```js
const express = require("express");
const { postgraphile } = require("postgraphile");

const app = express();

app.use(postgraphile(process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres:///"));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I hope the output is a basic code or a simple example implementing postgraphile in express.js

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, asking for tutorials or other off-site resources is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please review [what are good topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you encounter a specific issue while implementing postgraphile and can't find a similar question on SO, that would be a more appropriate question to post here. In the mean time, check out the docs or the [official chat](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/community-chat/).

Comment: I got here with the same question. It's clear that using postgraphile with express is common.  There's even a partial example in the docs.  But I've yet to find an example anywhere that shows how to get express to route to postgraphile.  I'm sure it's very simple for anyone who already knows express.  But for someone just trying out postgraphile, knowing I'll need some additional functionality like email and file upload in the future, it's a bit frustrating to not have a full example.  Instead I'll be spending some time learning express first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-library/

Here is an example you can start with:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { postgraphile } = require("postgraphile");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const app = express();
app.use(morgan("combined"));

const postgraphileOptionsDev = {
  subscriptions: true,
  watchPg: true,
  dynamicJson: true,
  setofFunctionsContainNulls: false,
  ignoreRBAC: false,
  showErrorStack: "json",
  extendedErrors: ["hint", "detail", "errcode"],
  appendPlugins: [require("@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector")],
  exportGqlSchemaPath: "schema.graphql",
  graphiql: true,
  enhanceGraphiql: true,
  allowExplain(req) {
    // TODO: customise condition!
    return true;
  },
  enableQueryBatching: true,
  legacyRelations: "omit",
  pgSettings(req) {
    /* TODO */
  },
};

const postgraphileOptionsProd = {
  subscriptions: true,
  retryOnInitFail: true,
  dynamicJson: true,
  setofFunctionsContainNulls: false,
  ignoreRBAC: false,
  extendedErrors: ["errcode"],
  appendPlugins: [require("@graphile-contrib/pg-simplify-inflector")],
  graphiql: false,
  enableQueryBatching: true,
  disableQueryLog: true,
  legacyRelations: "omit",
  pgSettings(req) {
    /* TODO */
  },
};

app.use(
  postgraphile(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "app_public",
    production ? postgraphileOptionsProd : postgraphileOptionsDev
  )
);

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`${production ? " PRODUCTION" : "‍ DEV"} server`);
  console.log(`GraphQL endpoint: http://localhost:${port}/graphql`);
  console.log(
    `GraphiQL (GraphQL IDE) endpoint: http://localhost:${port}/graphiql`
  );
});
```